# How to Dynamically Add OpenGraph URL in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, facebook-opengraph, next.js14

I'm working on a Next.js project and I'm trying to implement dynamic OpenGraph meta tags. Specifically, I want to set the og:url dynamically based on the current page URL. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this within the Next.js framework.

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {

   const metadata = await getRequest(
    `get-page-seo`
  );


  if (!metadata) {
    return null;
  }

  const previousImages = (await parent).openGraph?.images || [];

  let metatitle = metadata.meta_title;
  let metadescription = metadata.meta_description
     let metaogImage = metadata.og_image && metadata.seo.og_image;
  let metaKeyword = metadata.meta_key

  return {
    title: metatitle,
    description: metadescription,
    keywords: metaKeyword,
    openGraph: {
      images: [`${metaogImage}`, ...previousImages],
      type: "website",
    url : "" // This should be dynamic value will be same as browser url
          },
    twitter: {
      card: "summary_large_image",
      title: twitterTitle,
      description: twitterDescription,
      images: [`${twitterImage}`, ...previousImages],
    },
  };
}
```